# NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

This works in Python 2.7 but not in 3.5.

```
def file_read(self, input_text):

    doc = (file.read(file(input_text))).decode('utf-8', 'replace')
```

I'm trying to open this file, input_text is a path value from argparse.

I get this error.

```
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

I gather that Python 3.5 uses "open" instead of "file", but I don't quite get how to use open in a situation like this.

Comment: and what does the `str object has no attribute "read"` have to do with this?!

Comment: I wish people would be a bit slower on the gun in providing negative reputations.  Just getting started here, not trying to screw things up.

Comment: @FredZimmerman yes I agree with you on that

Answer (score 4):

Your original code works in Python 2.7 but it is bad style there. The `file` for this use was deprecated long time ago in favour of using `open`, and instead of calling the `file.read` passing the file as the argument you should have just called the `.read` method on the returned object.

The correct way to write the code you did on Python 2 would have been

```
with open(input_text) as docfile:
     doc = docfile.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace')
```

---

This does not work as such in Python 3, because `open` without mode would now default to reading unicode text. Furthermore it would assume the file is in native encoding and decode it with *strict* error handling. However, Python 3 actually makes working with text files easier than in Python 2, as you can pass the encoding and errors behaviour as arguments to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) itself:

```
with open(input_text, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as docfile:
     doc = docfile.read()
```